# PHP - Remove From String

Tags: php, string

I have a string: 
   `/123.456.789.10:111213` 
How could I remove the `'/'` and the `':111213'`, so I would still have `123.456.789.10`?

Comment: What are the rules?  Describe the rules to use.  Without any rules, the easiest answer is: `$string = '123.456.789.10';`.  Short of that, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$s = explode(":",$your_string);
echo = substr($s[0], 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo substr($string, 1, strpos($string, ':'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use regex for something so simple. String functions are much faster...

```
$old = '/123.456.789.10:111213';
$new = substr($old, strpos($old, '/') + 1, strpos($old, ':'));
echo $new;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to find position of ":" with [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) function and then use [substr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that, the simplest is probably this:

```php
$result = split('[/:]', $your_string);
$result = $result[1]; // gives "123.456.789.10"
```

Proof that it works: http://ideone.com/B6Kx6d

But it really depends how many variants of the initial string you want to support - another solution is below (proof: http://ideone.com/Y6oW6F):

```php
preg_match_all('</(.+)[:]>', $in, $matches);
$result $matches[1][0]; // gives "123.456.789.10"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use regular expressing matching do this:

```
input = "/123.456.789.10:111213";
echo preg_replace("/(\/)|(:111213)/", '', $input);
```

Though simple string functions (answered below) are probably faster for this specific case.